# Why is my SELECT Portion of my Syntax Showing Up as an Unrecognized Name Error on Big Query?

Tags: select, google-bigquery, syntax-error, average

I've been practicing the big query exercises provided by Coursera. For this specific exercise, I wanted to collect tree sizes from the tree size databases that big query provided to me.

My SELECT clause for this query ran:

```sql
SELECT 
  AVG(tree_dbh) 
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_census_2005` LIMIT 1000
```

but this one didn't:

```sql
SELECT 
  AVG(tree_dbh) 
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_census_1995` LIMIT 1000
```

I expected the lists of tree sizes to come up for both, since each database has the same columns by decade. The query for the 2005 query ran. The reason why the 1995 query didn't run is because big query didn't recognize AVG(tree_dbh) even though it wasn't a problem for the other one. What can I do to solve this problem so this query can run?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this column doesn't exist in that table. You can Ctrl + Click on the table name to open the table details and have a look for yourself:

https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1sbigquery-public-data!2snew_york_trees!3stree_census_1995

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I replaced tree_dbh with diameter and it solved the problem.